# E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success

Tags: apt

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  genders libgenders0 libltdl7
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  openssh-sftp-server ssh-import-id
Suggested packages:
  keychain libpam-ssh monkeysphere ssh-askpass molly-guard rssh
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```